# Split lines at intersections in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, line, splitting

How can I split all the lines in a feature class where they intersect with a second line feature.

I have a roads feature and a rail feature. I want the lines in the rail feature to split where ever it crosses a road. I'm looking to do it all at once with an overlay analysis tool. Like the Split Line at Point tool, but using lines as the input. Too many to do it manually.

Comment: What license level do you have?  If you have the Advanced license you could copy and paste all the rail lines into the roads, run planarize on all of them and then select and delete the rail lines,  (Or vice versa if you want the split the other way.)  You will need some attribute in the rail lines that allows you to select them and not the roads.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **feature to line** if you have an advanced licence (which is the case if you have split line at point). Below is a snapshot of the feature to line help in ArcGIS.

[image]

Comment: Use the Intersect tool with points as the output geometry, then use Split Lines at Point tool.  GP is supposed to be multi step most if the time and rarely do you get an extra tool that would just combine two steps in a model.

Comment: well, feature to line does the trick in this case, your two step method does work but it is not necessary. Planarize line could also do it but it is not a GP tool